# Action Method is not being executed while clicking button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have made a simple MVC program. I have created 3 buttons to insert,update or delete employee. But when I am clicking on the buttons, the action methods are not being executed & how come the same code work's in my friend's system but  not in mine. We both are using same MVC 4.  here's code

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit_Update_Delete_Insert_EMP()
    {

        EmployeeModel em = new EmployeeModel();
        ActionResult ar = View(em);
        return ar;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit_Update_Delete_Insert_EMP(EmployeeModel em, string Employee)
    {
        if (Employee == "Insert")
        { 
        }
        if (Employee == "Update")
        { 
        }
        if (Employee == "Delete")
        { 
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**View**

```
    @model Deepak_MVC_1.Models.EmployeeModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Edit_Update_Delete_Insert_EMP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using( Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(eid=>eid.E_ID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(eid=>eid.E_ID)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(fname=>fname.F_Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(fname=>fname.F_Name)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(lname=>lname.L_Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(lname=>lname.L_Name)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(age=>age.Age)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(age=>age.Age)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(salary=>salary.Salary)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(salary=>salary.Salary)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(dept=>dept.Dept)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(dept=>dept.Dept)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(doj=>doj.Doj)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(doj=>doj.Doj)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }   
            <button type="submit"name="Employee" value="Insert">Insert Employee</button>
            <button type="submit"name="Employee" value="Update">Update Employee</button>
            <button type="submit"name="Employee" value="Delete">Delete Employee</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your submit buttons are outside the form. Move them above the `}`

Answer (score 1):

The buttons are outside the `BeginForm() { }` block, so the `Employee` data value (determined by which button is clicked) is not submitted.